# How do I use InnerHTML to replace a html class with a script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Chrome Extension and would like to have some part of the website's content be replaced.

So the website's HTML is: `<div id="ad" class="ad-container "></div>` they have multiple 'id', but the class name remains the same.

The code I want to replace it with is: `<script src="link"></script>`

I was looking into something called 'InnerHTML", and saw this example: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('hello', 'hi');` but I'm not sure how to replace it with HTML, or change it so it works with a script tag.

Any help?

Comment: Remind me not to download your "extension"

Comment: So, you want to recreate adblock? Why not have a look at their code, its open source...

Comment: @RenevanderLende you have a point. thanks!!

Comment: @Liam haha! it's blocking ads, nothing bad!

Comment: I think @Liam meant that you are creating a 'some extension' but don't know basic JS, contemplating your final result....

Comment: @RenevanderLende Oh, it's definitely not going to be anything that good, but I figure it's a start to learn to get into this stuff

Comment: My idea too, hence my suggestion to have a look at their code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's scary though, be careful doing that.

```
for(let element of document.querySelectorAll('.ad-container')){
  let script = document.createElement('script')
  script.innerHTML = element.innerHTML
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  element.remove()
}
```